# Namespace conflict between two PHP third-party codes

Tags: php

I am currently facing a problem that is occurring because the `__()` method is already declared in another place.

Both of these methods are from third party libraries in PHP.

How am I supposed to fix this problem without changing the library code directly?

Comment: How do you use those libraries? I need a very detailed answer/example so I can help you.

Comment: One is Wordpress, the other is Laravel, a php framework

Comment: I know what they are. But how to you integrate them? How does your code look like?

Comment: `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` and then eventually

`require_once $path_to . '/wordpress/index.php';`

Comment: see my answer regarding the renaming of the `__()` function

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMO, It will be hard to not change anything. You should at least define a namespace for one of your third-libs.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

That could avoid your method name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to do this but depending on the use case it may be possible.

If you have a code similar to this:

```
include "something_laravel.php"
//then
include "something_wordpress.php";
```

you can temporary rename the `__()` function from laravel before the inclusion of wordpress, similar to this:

```
include "something_laravel.php"

rename_function('__', '__laravel' );

include "something_wordpress.php";
```

Depending on your own usage of the __() function, you can rename it back or keep it renamed.

Comment: This could work, however I really don't want to choose a soluton that requires an extra library. What I do know is that I can easily fix the problem by changing the code, but this seems a poor idea.

Comment: @space_food_ what is that extra library?

Comment: rename_function is not out of the box php functionality

Comment: Then, without changing the source code of one of the conflicting libraries, I have no solution. However, you could change the source code automatically, using a script.